# AT91SAM9263ek booting Linux with Device Tree failed

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot, device-tree

I have problem booting Linux 3.16.1. I have compiled sources from http://www.kernel.org with at91sam9263_defconfig.

I have added Flattened Device Tree support in Boot options.
Followin tips suggested in this (https://www.slideshare.net/softpapa/device-tree-support-on-arm-linux-8930303) presentation to turn on Support device tree in /proc but i don't have that option in menuconfig.

I have U-Boot bootloader version 2014.10rc2 which supports device tree.
I have generated dtb from script shipped with kernel:
make at91sam9263ek.dtb

And now i'm getting this error:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.5
OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on Feb 9 2011, 14:45:00.
Port /dev/ttyS0
Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
RomBOOT
>
U-Boot 2014.10-rc2-00200-g9170818-dirty (Sep 23 2014 - 15:16:39)
CPU: AT91SAM9263
Crystal frequency: 16.368 MHz
CPU clock : 199.919 MHz
Master clock : 99.960 MHz
DRAM: 64 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
NAND: 256 MiB
MMC: mci: 0
In: serial
Out: serial
Err: serial
Net: macb0

Warning: Your board does not use generic board. Please read
doc/README.generic-board and take action. Boards not
upgraded by the late 2014 may break or be removed.

Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0

U-Boot> tftp uImage
macb0: Starting autonegotiation...
macb0: Autonegotiation complete
macb0: link up, 100Mbps full-duplex (lpa: 0xcde1)
Using macb0 device
TFTP from server 192.168.1.247; our IP address is 192.168.1.240
Filename 'uImage'.
Load address: 0x22000000
Loading: #################################################################
#################################################################
#################################################################
##############
1.2 MiB/s
done

Bytes transferred = 3068016 (2ed070 hex)

U-Boot> tftp 20000000 dt
macb0: link up, 100Mbps full-duplex (lpa: 0xcde1)
Using macb0 device
TFTP from server 192.168.1.247; our IP address is 192.168.1.240
Filename 'dt'.
Load address: 0x20000000
Loading: #
340.8 KiB/s
done

Bytes transferred = 13279 (33df hex)

U-Boot> bootm 22000000 - 20000000
 ## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 22000000 ...
Image Name: Linux-3.16.1
Image Type: ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size: 3067952 Bytes = 2.9 MiB
Load Address: 20008000
Entry Point: 20008000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
 ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 20000000
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x20000000
Loading Kernel Image ... OK
Loading Device Tree to 23ea3000, end 23ea93de ... OK
Starting kernel ...
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
Error: unrecognized/unsupported device tree compatible list:
[ 'atmel,at91sam9263ek' 'atmel,at91sam9263' 'atmel,at91sam9' ]

Available machine support:
ID (hex) NAME
000004b2 Atmel AT91SAM9263-EK

Please check your kernel config and/or bootloader.
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
Add this line to .config:
CONFIG_MACH_AT91SAM9_DT=y

Comment: There are various ways to do this depending on kernel version and configurations.  This is one fix.

Comment: Direct editing of the .config file is frowned on.  Use `make menuconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct configuration for this board when using device tree is at91_dt_defconfig.

However, I am quite surprised to see someone trying to use such an old kernel. This board is fully supported upstream. Why don't you use v5.3? If this doesn't work, please report any bug, we will be happy to help correct them.